# Electromagnetic cooling

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, microwaves, cooling

Heat means stored kinetic energy in matter. Microwave owens and induction heaters works on increasing kinetic energy on matter. Is it possible to make inverse of this  heaters like cooler. Can we decrese kinetic energy by using like electromagnetic slower device? It will change many things in engineering.

Note:im searching it below from light frequency. There is laser applications on surface cooling but these are not reaching deep

Note2: also im searching a method which makes cooling process **from inside to outside**

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?):  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45318/fast-cool-down-of-things-in-the-kitchen

Comment: Its about heating and not explaining cooling. May be cooling requires a harmony or fornation of waves

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say there. This question of yours is very similar to the one I linked: is an 'inverse microwave' thermodynamically possible.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with a fridge... laser cooling of atoms and stochastic cooling of accelerator beams work just fine, of course, they are just not a suitable methods for large objects.

Comment: I too am not sure what you're asking.  But a thermocouple may be what you are looking for.  If you heat one end of a thermocouple and cool the other, you can produce electrical energy.  But it also works backwards: if you pass electricity through a thermocouple, one side will cool down and the other will heat up.  Look up "Peltier effect thermoelectric cooling."  If that's not what you want, try the "magnetocaloric effect," in which a material can be cooled by subjecting it to a varying magnetic field.  Magnetocaloric cooling can cool objects down to near absolute zero.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos and @ DavidRose I want to decrease atomic/molecular vibrations by using electromagnetic waves. Laser coilung do it. It works as sending photons and absorbing photons. But this is high frequency application and do not reaching deeper atoms. RF or microwave can reach deeper atoms. I wonder that is possible or not to slowing the atoms with RF or mw etc. Also i want to use it to make composite structures. First of all heat the material than cool the material from inside to outside or all of them at the same time*.

Comment: @acs To be very strict, it is rather *thermal energy* that is stored as kinetic energy in matter and not heat. *Heat* is rather energy "in transit" and not a stored amount. Just a note on the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Thermo-electric coolers use electricity to cool things. Not sure if that's what you're looking for, as it requires physical contact. But in general, it's a lot easier to make heat than to remove it.

Comment: This effects from outside to inside. So this isnt the answer

Comment: @acs The cooling Dave talks about is not external. It is the material itself cooling down in some part of it as electrons move and carry thermal energy along with them from within the  material. Consider it a redistribution of thermal energy rather than a cooling process from the outside.